# Assembly Theory

Tags: assembly, theory

We're working with assembly. I'm kind of lost. This is a practice question on a study guide:

---

Using hypothetical machines (3-address, 2-address, 1-address and 0-address) and the
following commands:

```
load= puts value in address
add = +
mult = *
sub = -
lda=load in accumulator
sta = loads from accumulator to memory
push=copies to the stack
pop=copies from the stack
```

Show for each machine the instructions to perform the following task:

```
F=E+(A-C) – (B*E)
```

---

A. Can someone explain how those 4 different machine types differ in terms of the code?
B. Can someone show me how to do one of the four as a place to start?

Comment: What does any of that have to do with x86 assembly?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I guess it's theory of assembly? Kind of? I didn't design the class, that's for sure.

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't have x86 or x86-64 tags here, since they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: What would you suggest? Just 'assembly'?

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the title, since your question has nothing to do with Visual Studio, too.  Then retag with something that makes sense.  I guess assembly by itself is ok... is there a theory tag?

Comment: Oh the title is accidental, that carried over from a different question. my mistake. yeah, i was just trying to attract some assembly people since this would be their department of understanding.

Comment: Useful info here: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/PL-Architecture/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
3-Addr. (Result and ops from memory)
mult b, b, e
sub  f, a, c
sub  f, f, b
add  f, e, f

2-Addr (Shared result and one op)
mult b, e
sub  a, c
load f, e
add  f, a
sub  f, b

1-Addr (Accu only)
lda  b
mult e
sta  b
lda  a
sub  c
sta  a
lda  e
add  a
sub  b
sta  f

0-Addr (Stack only)
push e
push a
push c
sub
add
push b
push e
mult
sub
pop f
```

Comment: A few years later, looking back through old SO questions of mine, I wanted to say that this explanation was REALLY helpful to me at the time. Thank you very much.